# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN Stack and Angular 6. My schema has following values.
UserName: default,
ExtrudedHeight:250,

There is a button in html page. After I click the button I want to get values of the collection where the userName= default.

For that I created a get method in router,

//Get single value by userName

```
router.get('/:userName', function(req, res, next) {
alert(Came to router);
    extrudedHeight.findOne({'userName': req.params.userName}, function (err, post) {
        console.log(req.params.userName);
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });
```

service.ts

```
 getExtrudedHeight(userName) {
        return this.http.get('/extrudedHeight/' + userName, {
        });
 }
```

html

```
<div class="">
      <button type='button' (click)="setDefaultValues()" class="btn btn-sm btn-rectangle btn-default text-case">Default Values</button>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
Class{
    extrudedHeightValue = {};



ngOnInit(){
this.setDefaultValues();
}

  setDefaultValues(){
    this.extrudedHeightService.getExtrudedHeight("default").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.extrudedHeightValue = data;
    });

  }

}
```

My question is I have added an alert in the router but when I hit the button it does not show. Is that mean my routing is wrong?

I am getting following errors as well.
[image: error]

Comment: remove this line `alert(Came to router);` and try

Comment: `this.http.get('/extrudedHeight/' + userName, {});` ?? shouldn't there be a Domain here?? like: `localhost:8080/extrudedHeight/...` ? And router in API should have the path like: `'/extrudedHeight/:userName'`. Also there is No alert is NodeJs I guess.. alert should be on Client side

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The error was due to method call in ngOnInit function in .ts file. But no idea about the reason.

Comment: data comes as {_id: "5bb36116c36ccc37d02d7663", userName: "default", extrudedHeight: 250, __v: 0} Do you have any idea of accessing it in setDefaultValues() method?